# Como crear una base de datos SQLite en Android + LIBGDX

Tags: android, android-studio, sqlite, android-sqlite, libgdx

estoy intentando crear una base de datos SQLite que no desaparezca despues de cerrar la app, y estoy probando con esto:

```
scoreHelper = newScoreSQLiteHelper(this.getApplicationContext(),"dbtest",null,1);

db = scoreHelper.getWritableDatabase();

----------------------------------------------------------------------

public ScoreSQLiteHelper(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
        super(context, name, null, 1);
```

He probado a intentar meterle el path,con el path :memory: se elimina la bd cuando se cierra la app, y al path real donde se guarda la base de datos en android no se puede acceder si no está ruteado. Ahora estoy intentando conseguir el context pero en esta app con libgdx no se porque no puedo cogerlo, así que eso que esta ahí no funciona bien.

También he probado sin éxito con la siguiente instrucción, la cual tampoco funciona:

```
db = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase("mydb1", null);
```

Si alguien tiene idea...

Answer (score 0):

```
tienes que crear una clase con el nombre que prefieras para el siguiente ejemplo AdminSqlite y luego extender a SQLiteOpenHelper


public class AdminSqlite extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final String DBNAME = "dbsqlite";
    public static final int IDDB = 1;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
}
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        Log.i("TAG", "version table from " + oldVersion + " to " + newVersion);
        if (newVersion > oldVersion) {


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Si, eso lo había probado también, el problema es que eso necesita un constructor, y a ese constructor hace falta pasarle un context. El problema entonces es que yo no se como acceder a un context desde el paquete Android usando LIBGDX ya que mi clase principal extiende a `Game` y no extiende a la clase `Aplication`.

Answer (score 0):

El sistema de preferencias de LibGDX es lo que buscas!

1. Usa SQLite
2. No se borrará nada de lo que guardes dentro al cerrar la app
3. Es multiplataforma
4. [Aquí te dejo la wiki](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Preferences)

```java
public void saveScore(int score) {
    Preferences preferences = Gdx.app.getPreferences("My Preferences");
    preferences.putInteger("Score", score);
    preferences.flush(); // Esta línea es muy importante, te asegura que los cambios se guardaron
}
```